# Struggling to adjust a toggle button and its text for my weather app

Tags: javascript, html, css

first post here!

I have a weather app I am making with HTML, CSS, and Javascript, and I'm using the Open Weather Map API. So far I'm prety happy with my project! It looks good, and it's working as it should for the most part.

My problem however is I am trying to add a toggle that switches between imperial and metric units. The default is imperial, and the toggle button does work for switching the units to metric, however the text appears over the button (I want it to the right), and there is a problem with how the button transforms when it is clicked. I'm torn between if I need to fix my Javascript, my CSS, or both.

See for yourself, here it is on Code Pen:
https://codepen.io/sti_ck/pen/ExdWXmw

Here is the code as a Gist:
https://gist.github.com/sstickk/f5513e7c77786544f3d464c57d36ef6e

I've tried tweaking both CSS and Javascript, but I have spent more time trying to fix it with javascript. But seems like I'm running in circles at this point. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Old JS for the toggle function:

```
toggleUnits: function () {
        if (this.units.temperature === "imperial") {
            this.units.temperature = "metric";
            this.units.temperatureSymbol = " °C";
            this.units.windSpeed = "meter/sec";
            this.units.windSpeedSymbol = " kmh";
        } else {
            this.units.temperature = "imperial";
            this.units.temperatureSymbol = " °F";
            this.units.windSpeed = " mph";
            this.units.windSpeedSymbol = " mph";
        }
        const button = document.querySelector("#unit-toggle");
        button.innerText = "Switch to " + (this.units.temperature === "imperial" ? "Celsius" : "Fahrenheit");
        button.style.color = "#000"; // Add this line to change text color        this.fetchWeather(document.querySelector(".search-bar").value);
    },
```

Current code for the function:

```
toggleUnits: function () {
        const button = document.querySelector("#unit-toggle");
        if (this.units.temperature === "imperial") {
            this.units.temperature = "metric";
            this.units.temperatureSymbol = " °C";
            this.units.windSpeed = "meter/sec";
            this.units.windSpeedSymbol = " kmh";
            button.innerText = "Switch to Fahrenheit";
        } else {
            this.units.temperature = "imperial";
            this.units.temperatureSymbol = " °F";
            this.units.windSpeed = " mph";
            this.units.windSpeedSymbol = " mph";
            button.innerText = "Switch to Celsius";
        }
        button.classList.toggle('checked');
        this.fetchWeather(document.querySelector(".search-bar").value);
    },
    search: function () {
        this.fetchWeather(document.querySelector(".search-bar").value);
    }

};
```

My current CSS for the toggle button:

```
#unit-toggle {
    width: 2.2em;
    height: 1.2em;
    border-radius: 1em;
    position: absolute;
    right: 8em;
    top: 93%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    cursor: pointer;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    padding-right: 0.2em;
  }
  
  #unit-toggle.checked {
    background-color: #2196F3;
  }
  
  #unit-toggle.checked::before {
    transform: translateX(1em);
    left: unset;
  right: calc(100% + 5px);
  }
  
  
  #unit-toggle::before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 0.1em;
    left: 0.1em;
    width: 1em;
    height: 1em;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-color: #fff;
    transition: transform 0.2s ease-in-out;
  }
  
  #unit-toggle.checked::before {
    transform: translateX(1em);
  }
  
  #unit-toggle.checked {
    background-color: #1012ad;
  }
  
  #unit-toggle.checked::before {
    transform: translateX(1em);
  }
```

Anything helps! Thank you for taking the time today to help me.

Comment: Originally you have two `<span>` inside the `<button>`, but then you effectively remove them from the DOM using `.innerText = '...'`. Also, for something that only has two possible states, a checkbox with a `'change'` event listener should be preferred.